# Open folder on button click with "My files" application

Tags: java, android, directory

I am making android application. On button click I just need to open specific folder where I have pdf's so user can choose some pdf to read from that folder.

I manage to list all files from pdf folder, but that is not what I need. Most logical solution is just to open folder with "My files" app which is already part of Android OS. Is there any whey to do this on android?

Comment: i just wanted to mention that "My files" is not part of the Android OS. It is just part of some ROMs. You can't assume "My files" is available on all devices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is working without "My Files" app which, is better solution.

```
    public class AndroidListFilesActivity extends ListActivity {

    File root;
    File pdf;

    private List<String> fileList = new ArrayList<String>();


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getAbsolutePath());
        // ListDir(root);

        pdf = new File(root, "PDF");
        ListDir(pdf);
    }

    void ListDir(File f) {
        File[] files = f.listFiles();
        fileList.clear();
        for (File file : files) {
            fileList.add(file.getPath());
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> directoryList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, fileList);

        setListAdapter(directoryList);

    }

    public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        //selection.setText(fileList.indexOf(simple_list_item_1));
        OpenPdf(fileList.get(position).toString());
    }

    public void OpenPdf(String path)
    {
          File file = new File(path);
          if (file.exists()) {
              Uri p = Uri.fromFile(file);
              Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
              intent.setDataAndType(p, "application/pdf");
              intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

              try {
                  startActivity(intent);
              } 
              catch (ActivityNotFoundException e){
              }
          }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Be careful. Not all Android devices have a "My files" app. So the best way is to create your own listing/file explorer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my code for listing files, how to open pdf files now on click.

```
    public class AndroidListFilesActivity extends ListActivity {

    private List<String> fileList = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getAbsolutePath());    
        File pdf = new File(root, "PDF");
        ListDir(pdf);
    }

    void ListDir(File f) {
        File[] files = f.listFiles();
        fileList.clear();
        for (File file : files) {
            fileList.add(file.getPath());
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> directoryList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, fileList);
        setListAdapter(directoryList);
    }

}
```